# How to render a 2d side-scroller game

Tags: rendering, 2d

I do not really understand the way I'm suppose to render a side-scroller?  How do I know what to render when my character move?  What kind of positionning should I use for the characters?
I hope my question is clear

Comment: I'm doing a similar project, heh.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by a "side scroller"?

Comment: "Side scroller" typically refers to a certain type of video game. Imagine a 2d viewport to a 2d environment. The viewport can only slide left/right. wikipedia says: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-scrolling_video_game

Comment: @Apoc: in a 2D side-scroller (as in "real side-scroller", no rotating/zooming thing) typically you have a "level map" which is much bigger than your screen (Image a picture that would be 10 000 pixels wide) and a "viewport" whose (X,Y) can be (*"hero character X - physical screen height in pixels / 2"*, *"hero character Y - physical screen height in pixels / 2"*). You typically render only the part of the "level map" that is on screen and only the entities that are on screen (btw your level can be made of tiles [say 8x8 or 16x16 tiles] or not: back in the days it basically *had* to be tiles).

Comment: One thing I'm having hard time figuring out, is whenever we move what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i've found to do it is have a characterX and characterY variable [integer or float, whatever you want]  Then have a cameraX and cameraY variable.  Every object in the scene is drawn at theObjectX-cameraX, theObjectY-cameraY...

CameraX/CameraY are tweened by a similar-to-midpoint formula so eventually they'll reach playerx/playery`[Cx = (Cx*99+Px)/100]` ... yeah

By doing this, every object moves in the stage's space, and is transformed only on render [saving you from headaches]

Answer (score 0):

- Use a matrix to define a camera reference frame.
- Use space partitioning to split up your level into screens/windows.

Think of your player sprite as any other entity, like enemies and interactive objects.
Now what you want is the abstraction of a camera. You can define a camera as a 3x3 matrix with this layout:

```
[rotX_X, rotY_X, 0]
[rotX_Y, rotY_Y, 0]
[transX, transY, 1]
```

The 2x2 sub-matrix in the top-left corner is a rotation matrix. transX and transY defines the translation part, i.e the origin. You also get scaling for free. Just simply scale the rotation part with a scalar, and you have yourself a zoom.

For this to work properly with rotation, your sprites need to be polygons/primitives, say like triangles or quads; you can't just apply the matrix to the positions of the sprites when drawing. If you don't need rotation, just transforming the center point will work fine.
If you want the camera to follow the player, use the player's position as the camera origin. That is the translation vector [transX, transY]
So how do you apply the matrix to entity positions and model vertices? You do a vector-matrix multiplication.
**v' = vM^-1**, where v' is the new vector, v is the old vector, and M^-1 is the matrix inverse.  A camera needs to be an inverse transform because it defines a local coordinate system. An analogy could be: If you are in front of me and I turn left from my reference frame, I am turning your right. This applies to all affine and linear transformations, like scaling, rotation and translation.

Split up your level into sub-parts so you can cull objects and scenery which does not need to be rendered. Your viewport is of a certain size/resolution. Only render scenery and entities which intersect with your viewport. Instead of checking each and every entity against the viewport bounds, assign each entity to a certain sub-screen and test the bounds of the sub-screen against the viewport and camera bounds. If your divide your levels into parts which are the same size as your viewport, then the maximum number of screens visible 
at any particular time is:

- 2 if your camera only scrolls left and right.
- 4 if your camera scrolls left, right, up and down.
- 4 if your camera scrolls in any direction, and additionally can be rotated.

A screen-change is an event you can use to activate entities belonging to that screen. That could be enemies, background animations, doors or whatever you like.

Comment: I played my first side-scroller probably before you were born and I'm pretty sure you don't know what the definition of a side-scroller is:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-scrolling_video_game I've actually *worked* on Amiga side-scroller and I can tell you rotating the whole screen and zooming in & out is **NOT** what side-scrollers are about ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first foray into writing a side-scroller, I'd suggest considering using an already existing game engine (like [Construct](http://www.scirra.com/) or [Gamemaker](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/) or [XNA](http://www.xna.com/) or whatever fits your experience level) so you don't have to worry about what order to render things and how to make it all work.  Mess with that a bit--probably exploring a few of them--to get a feel for how they do things then venture out to your own once you've gotten used to it.
Not that there's anything wrong with baptism by fire but it can get pretty overwhelming in my opinion.