# Problem decrementing in Java with '-='

Tags: java, android

I'm making a scrolling game on Android and am having a hard time figuring out why the code below does not decrement past 0.

Objects start at the end of the screen (so the x position is equal to the width of the screen) the objects move accross the screen by decrementing their x positions. I want them to scroll off of the screen, but when the x position hits 0, the objects just stay at 0, they do not move into the negatives.

Here is my code to move objects on the screen

```
private void incrementPositions(long delta) {

    float incrementor = (delta / 1000F) * Globals.MAP_SECTION_SPEED;        

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, MapSection>> column : scrollingMap.entrySet()) {
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, MapSection> row : column.getValue().entrySet()) {
            MapSection section = row.getValue();
            section.x -= incrementor;           
        }
    }       
}
```

It works ok if I change

```
section.x -= incrementor;
```

to

```
section.x = section.x - (int)incrementor;
```

but if i do that the scrolling doesn't appear as smooth.

Comment: Are you sure your x position is not simply being clamped to 0 when it's drawn? If you inspect the actual value, is it 0 or is it negative?

Comment: `incrementor` isn't precisely `0.5f` (or should that be `-0.5f`?), is it?

Comment: this is pretty much totally OT, but from what I see of your code it appears your sidescroller is implemented by changing the positions of all the objects every frame -- have you considered instead having fixed positions for them (or positions updated with their motion only) and scrolling the viewport instead?  This means when you draw you subtract the viewport coordinates from each object's coordinates.  It makes for much easier to understand code IMHO.

Comment: @rmeador Thanks for the comment, you wouldn't happen to have any links describing this method would you?

Comment: @hanesjw: I'm not aware of any articles that describe this technique, it's just something you learn to do pretty early on because the alternative is so painful.  I did however find an SO question where the first answer describes it in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626884/how-to-render-a-2d-side-scroller-game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try storing the section as a float value and only converting it to an int if needed at the end of the calculation (only for rendering).